# Setting UP IIS for www access

Tags: iis7

I have server that I connect to via Remote Access. On it I have IIS7 and a web application that works. The server itself has an static ip address that I can ping, also I set up filezilla server and I can connect normally with FTP.

But I cant connect over internet (browser) to that address. address is 75.99.xxx.xxx.

As I said I can ping that address remotely and it replies. What is strange is when I connect remotely to that machine and enter 75.99.xxx.xxx. in browser it shows the website, identical if I entered localhost.

I have turned off Firewall completely.

What can I do?

THIS IS ADDITION TO QUESTION:
The following command `C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -n -a -b`
gives the following:
Active Connections

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:21             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 ftpsvc
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:111            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 RpcSs
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1039           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1047           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1048           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:2049           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:2382           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[sqlbrowser.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TermService
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:5631           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[wininit.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 eventlog
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Schedule
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[lsass.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49172          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[services.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49690          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[msmdsrv.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49697          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[sqlservr.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:50093          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 PolicyAgent
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:21        75.127.70.6:54091      ESTABLISHED
 ftpsvc
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    75.99.69.147:3389      92.36.137.24:44307     ESTABLISHED
 TermService
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      24.228.231.27:39178    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      24.238.35.39:54377     ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.121.160.27:50740    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.121.160.27:53841    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.121.160.27:59525    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.122.150.107:3607    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.127.61.178:1071     ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      69.127.61.178:50075    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      74.102.7.206:49375     ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      108.27.213.204:3604    ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:5631      173.3.138.76:50825     ESTABLISHED
[AWAccess.exe]
 TCP    75.99.69.147:49174     212.54.132.70:5721     ESTABLISHED
[AgentMon.exe]
 TCP    127.0.0.1:49698        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[sqlservr.exe]
 TCP    [::]:21                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 ftpsvc
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:111               [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
 RpcSs
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:1039              [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:1047              [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:1048              [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:2049              [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:2382              [::]:0                 LISTENING
[sqlbrowser.exe]
 TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 TermService
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:47001             [::]:0                 LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:49152             [::]:0                 LISTENING
[wininit.exe]
 TCP    [::]:49153             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 eventlog
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:49154             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Schedule
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING
[lsass.exe]
 TCP    [::]:49172             [::]:0                 LISTENING
[services.exe]
 TCP    [::]:49697             [::]:0                 LISTENING
[sqlservr.exe]
 TCP    [::]:50093             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 PolicyAgent
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:49698            [::]:0                 LISTENING
[sqlservr.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:111            *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
 W32Time
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
 IKEEXT
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:928            *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:1039           *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:1047           *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:1048           *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:1434           *:*
[sqlbrowser.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:2049           *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
 IKEEXT
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
 Dnscache
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:5632           *:*
[AWAccess.exe]
 UDP    75.99.69.147:137       *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    75.99.69.147:138       *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:123               *:*
 W32Time
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    [::]:500               *:*
 IKEEXT
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    [::]:940               *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:1039              *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:1047              *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:1048              *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:1434              *:*
[sqlbrowser.exe]
 UDP    [::]:2049              *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [::]:4500              *:*
 IKEEXT
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
 Dnscache
[svchost.exe]
 UDP    [::1]:111              *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [2001:0:9d38:6ab8:309c:9ca:b49c:ba6c]:111  *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [2002:4b63:4593::4b63:4593]:111  *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [fe80::309c:9ca:b49c:ba6c%11]:111  *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
 UDP    [fe80::fce6:58e5:c966:70aa%13]:111  *:*
Can not obtain ownership information
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mask your IP address in your netstat output, I assume you are trying to access your site by navigating to `http://75.99.69.147`?  If the site works fine when you are on the server itself, but not when trying to access from outside, there could be one (or more) items causing the site not to work correctly:

1. Are there multiple sites on the web server under the same IP address?  If so, then you may need to configure a host header in the bindings on your IIS configuration if they are all being accessed over port 80.
2. As was mentioned in an earlier answer, if you turned off Windows firewall and it still did not work, is there an external firewall that has not been configured correctly to allow traffic through?
3. Another sometimes hidden gotcha is the default gateway that is configured on your server.  If you have configured a static IP on your server, then you will most likely need to configure the default gateway as well so that the outbound packets know how to respond.  If you are running this server out of your home, that gateway IP address would likely be that of your router depending on how your network is setup.
4. Within IIS, something to check would be the 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions' configuration for both the server and site.  If you select this in IIS Manager, click 'Edit Feature Settings...' on the right column and verify that the 'Access for unspecified clients:' setting is set to 'Allow' and not 'Deny'.

Hope one of those help.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the Firewall back on for a start.  Depending on who your server is with there may be another firewall present in the set-up, maybe in front of your server controlled via a control panel or some sort.

Have you tried opening a port on the firewall rather than turn it off?

The server know its own IP address (internal and external) hence that will work when working on the Remote Desktop (RD)

S

Comment: I have entered new rule in Firewall explicitly allowing all traffic on port 80. Still no result

Comment: Do you know if there is another firewall? Who is your host with? in the firewall you are accessing if the FTP port turned on? if so when you turn it off does your FTP access still work?

Comment: When I turn it on/off, FTP still works without any issues. At this time, I do not know if there is another firewall somewhere else. I need to check it then.

Comment: I suspect there is another firewall coming into play here. Check on your host Control Panel.

Comment: There is no router or anything. PC is hooked directly on internet. I am using Windows 2008Server

Comment: No i mean on the remote server...where is the server hosted?

Comment: There is static IP address on 75.99.xxx.xxx. Server is hooked directly on it. I was told there is nothing between the server and the internet that might create problems...

Comment: Sorry i can see the full IP address...

Comment: I have updated the main question

Comment: Your webserver is not bound to the external IP address according to your net stat output.